# Executing fetch requests in the background using MagicalRecord

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, magicalrecord

This is what I have so far:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *privateContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_context];
[privateContext performBlock:^{
        Cat* object = [Cat MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"id" withValue:catId inContext:privateContext];
        // Convert your fetched objects into object IDs which can be pulled out of the main context
        NSString *privateObjectID = [object valueForKey:@"objectID"];

        // Return to our main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            ???
        });
    }];
```

Is this the right thing to do? If so, how do I get my object back into the main thread? (the ??? area above)

If I just do this:

```
NSManagedObjectContext* context = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];
Cat* object = [Cat MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"id" withValue:catId inContext:context];
```

The UI gets blocked, so I'm trying to figure out how to do the fetch without blocking the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

The code inside the block (the one performed on the main thread) should be:

```
NSManagedObjectContext* c = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];
Cat* o = (Cat*)[context objectWithID:object.objectID];
//access `o` so it will get faulted in by the main context
//I think you could use: [o valueForKey:nil] or [o didAccessValueForKey:nil]
```

The important thing is to keep the BG fetched objects in (coordinator) cache while accessing them from the main context.